# Getting error Field `BaseStats.baseStats.hp' must be fully assigned before control leaves the constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to figure this out but have not been able to so here it is. Cannot implicitly convert type `int` to `BaseStats.Stat`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BaseStats : MonoBehaviour {

    public struct baseStats {
    public string name;
    public int level;
    public Stat hp;
    public int ap;

    public int strength;
    public int toughness;
    public int agility;
    public int intelligence;
    public int willPower;
    public int luck;

    public int attack;
    public int hitPercentage;
    public int defence;
    public int evasionPercentage;
    public int abilityAttack;
    public int abilityDefence;
    public int abilityDefencePercentage;

    public int exp;

        public baseStats(string Name, int Level, int Hp, int Ap, int Strength, int Toughness, int Agility, int Intelligence, int WillPower, int Luck, int Attack, int HitPercentage, int Defence, int EvasionPercentage, int AbilityAttack, int AbilityDefence, int AbilityDefencePercentage, int Exp) {
            name = Name;
            level = Level;
            hp = Hp;
            ap = Ap;

            strength = Strength;
            toughness = Toughness;
            agility = Agility;
            intelligence = Intelligence;
            willPower = WillPower;
            luck = Luck;

            attack = Attack;
            hitPercentage = HitPercentage;
            defence = Defence;
            evasionPercentage = EvasionPercentage;
            abilityAttack = AbilityAttack;
            abilityDefence = AbilityDefence;
            abilityDefencePercentage = AbilityDefencePercentage;

            exp = Exp;

        }
    }

    public class Stat {
        int current;
        int max;
    }

    void Start() {

        baseStats mainChar = new baseStats( 
            "Truth",
            99,
            9999,
            999,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            100,
            255,
            255, 
            100,
            7777777);

        print(mainChar.level);

    }
}
```

I'm trying to get HP where it has a current and max and this is how the tutorial is teaching me. Unfortunately the tutorial is in unityscript whereas I want to do my coding in c# and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you pass an `int` (`Hp`) through the constructor and you assign it to a variable of type `Stat` (`hp`):

```
hp = Hp;
```

Change the constructor to:

```
public baseStats(string Name, int Level, Stat Hp /*...*/){
    //...
}
```

**EDIT:**

> Argument #3' cannot convert int' expression to type BaseStats.Stat'
>   and The best overloaded method match for
>   BaseStats.baseStats.baseStats(string, int, BaseStats.Stat, int, int,
>   int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)' has
>   some invalid arguments

Your second problem is that changing the constructor you also have to pass the right object to the constructor:

```
baseStats mainChar = new baseStats( 
            "Truth",
            99,
            9999, //It's an int and you have to pass an object of type Stat
            999,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            100,
            255,
            255, 
            100,
            7777777);
```

Change it to:

```
Stat myStat = new Stat(); //create the object needed

baseStats mainChar = new baseStats( 
            "Truth",
            99,
            myStat,  //pass it!
            999,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            255,
            100,
            255,
            255, 
            100,
            7777777);
```

Comment: ok I changed int Hp to Stat Hp and now get Argument `#3' cannot convert `int' expression to type `BaseStats.Stat'   and   The best overloaded method match for `BaseStats.baseStats.baseStats(string, int, BaseStats.Stat, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: thanks! now how would I add in the actual numbers of current and max Hp. ps that got rid of the errors!!!

Comment: Ok guys thanks so much, I think I need to do more studying before I tackle this problem, I just don't understand it lol Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: You have to make the fields public: `public int current; //...`. Then after creating the object assign to them a value: `myStat.current = 10; //... `.

Comment: I see, why doesnt the guy in the tut just create a hp current and hp max instead I dont understand haha but youve helped so much thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor you are assigning:

```
hp = Hp;
```

Where your parameter `HP` is of type `int` and you have defined your field `hp` as `Stat`

```
public Stat hp;
```

That is the reason you are getting the error, I believe you want to define your field as `int` as well. Also as a side note its better if you follow [.Net naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @user2279258, or you may define your field as of type `int` depends on your requirement. But from the call it seems you are passig it an integer

Comment: how would I pass Stat to hp so that hp has a current and max value if I define hp as an int? and thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Stat` should be `Enum` as per the usage you provided instead of a `class` -

```
public enum Stat
{
   int current;
   int max;
}
```

This is an issue of type conversion. Either pass parameter as Enum (Stat) -

```
public baseStats(string Name, int Level, Stat Hp, ....)
```

Or typecast it to enum (Stat) before assignment -

```
hp = (Stat)Hp;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the cast is not possible due to the fact that `Stat` is defined as a `class` and not an `enum`.

Comment: Oh, i see. I haven't noticed that. This should have been enum instead though as per its usage.

Comment: I see so ill try changing the class to enum also for clarification, im following a unityscript tut trying to convert it to c# and he defined his Stat as a class so that maybe where I went wrong... thank you all for helping so much!!!